# How can I trim all elements in a list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying the following

```
string tl = " aaa, bbb, ccc, dddd             eeeee";

var tags = new List<string>();
tags.AddRange(tl.Split(','));
tags.ForEach(x => x = x.Trim().TrimStart().TrimEnd());

var result = String.Join(",", tags.ToArray());
```

But it doesn't work, the tags always come back as " aaa", " bbb".

How can I trim all elements in a list?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
// you can omit the final ToArray call if you're using .NET 4
var result = string.Join(",", tl.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray());
```

If you only need the final result string, rather than the intermediate collection, then you could use a regular expression to tidy the string. You'll need to benchmark to determine whether or not the regex outperforms the split-trim-join technique:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(tl, @"(?<=^|,) +| +(?=,|$)", "");
```

Comment: This won't work the way he wants. The problem is that there is no comma between dddd and eeeee.

Comment: @Justin: Where does the OP say that this is a problem? As far as I can tell there should be four elements in the list: *"aaa"*, *"bbb"*, *"ccc"* and *"dddd             eeeee"*.

Comment: I kinda figured. And you're right. I read too much into and made an assumption.

Comment: @Bruno: The elements in your `tags` list are references to the relevant strings. The `x` arguments passed into your delegate in the `ForEach` statement are *copies* of the references from the list, so when you assign the trimmed string back to `x`, you're replacing the *copy* of the reference, not the actual reference that's held in the list.

Comment: Note that splitting and joining by comma causes problems if an entry is comma separated

Answer (score 10):

Ran into the same problem. @Lee already explained that Lamda .ForEach() uses a copy.

You can write an Extension Method like this and use a for loop (foreach also not possible):

```
public static class StringListExtensions
{
    public static void TrimAll(this List<string> stringList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stringList.Count; i++)
        {
            stringList[i] = stringList[i].Trim(); //warning: do not change this to lambda expression (.ForEach() uses a copy)
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var productNumbers = new List<string>(){ "11111", " 22222 " }
productNumbers.TrimAll();
```

should result in: List(){ "11111", "22222" }

I didn't use the split and re-join solution (chosen solution) because there can be a comma inside one of the string items. The regex version is not self explanatory. This is old-school but safer and can be easily understood...

Comment: My favourite, as it extends the list's capabilities. I got my version to return the list after trim, this allows me to chain it with other processing methods. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

The reason your approach doesn't work is that the `x` is a copy of the current string reference being processed in the `ForEach` call (i.e. local to the delegate). Therefore the assignment doesn't affect the item referenced in the list.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
List<string> lstSelect = string_test.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

What's going on is that you're trying to modify a collection using a `foreach` statement- which is a no-no.  Collections cannot be modified with a `foreach`.

You'll need to modifiy it a `for` loop, or, using lambdas, you can use LukeH's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that there is no comma between dddd and eeeee. If you want those to be separate, you need to split on `' '`, strip the commas, and then trim extra whitespace.

```
string tl = " aaa, bbb, ccc, dddd                eeeee";

var result = t1.Split(' ').Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty())
                          .Select(s => s.Replace(',','').Trim())
                          .ToArray();
```

Comment: just remember to filter out all the empty elements after you split by space:
tl.Split(' ').Select(s => s.Replace(",","").Trim()).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray()

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done through LINQ one liner:

Just remember rule of Thumb :

**SELECT**  -> For transforming the elements

**WHERE**   -> For Filtering the elements

Now, **we can use the SELECT clause to Transform all the elements**:

```
List<string> listString = new List<string>(){"abc ", "xyz ", " Abc ", "  zx"};
listString = listString.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
```

Thats all and things are done.